# React changing the 'q' of an API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a project in which the user can select a singer in a input box and the some of their music previews are displayed on the screen. It's just a prototype, and I'll improve it later. But I noticed that when I call the API(in this case I'm using the Deezer API), I'm having a hard time trying to discover how to change the query 'q' (which is the param that holds the singer). Here's the code:

```
 import React from "react";

 class MusicList extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
     super();
    this.state = {
       data: [],
       selectedArtist: ''
     }
   this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

   componentDidMount() {
   fetch("https://deezerdevs-deezer.p.rapidapi.com/search?q=eminem", {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "x-rapidapi-host": "deezerdevs-deezer.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key": "20438f9eb4mshb2a68ca50196b46p1d55a5jsn2dbdc2b012cd"
  }
 })
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({
      data: response.data
    })
  });
 }

   handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      selectedArtist: e.target.value
    })
   }

 render() {
  return (
     <div>
      <form>
        <input 
          type="text" 
          placeholder="Search..."
          value={this.state.selectedArtist}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <button>Search</button>
         </form>
        </div>
      );
     }
   }

    export default MusicList;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to separate the fetch part of your code as a separate function at first step; like below:

```
function getSingerList(query) {
fetch(`https://deezerdevs-deezer.p.rapidapi.com/search?q=${query}`, {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "x-rapidapi-host": "deezerdevs-deezer.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key": "20438f9eb4mshb2a68ca50196b46p1d55a5jsn2dbdc2b012cd"
  }
 })
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({
      data: response.data
    })
  });
}
```

then create an input and keep track of input value by useState, check this simple tutorial from [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html), then fetch the data  by calling the function with query parameter when you need in submit of your search input field you've created!

```
handleSubmitSearch = e => {
   e.preventDefault();

   getSingerList(this.state.query)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to pass the query (aka the artist name) to the function that calls Deezer API, so create a function that only retrieve the results from freezer:

```
fetchArtist (name) {
 fetch(`https://deezerdevs-deezer.p.rapidapi.com/search?q=${name}`, {
   method: "GET",
   headers: {
    "x-rapidapi-host": "deezerdevs-deezer.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key": "20438f9eb4mshb2a68ca50196b46p1d55a5jsn2dbdc2b012cd"
   }
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({
      data: response.data
    })
  });

}
```

Second you need to edit your `componentDidMount` to call the newly created function:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchArtist('eminem')
}
```

Then if you want to search for an artist when the user types something, then in your `handleChange` do this:

```
   handleChange(e) {
    const artistName = e.target.value
    this.setState({
      selectedArtist: artistName
    })
    this.fetchArtist(artistName)
   }
```

If you want to make the search ONLY when you click `search`, then you need to add an `OnSubmit` to your form:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
```

And then create another function called `handleSubmit` and move the `fetchArtist` call inside it

Working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/Sletheren/shgx4bwk/7/

Comment: @Gabriel22233 I've added a code example, if it helps then please upvote and mark the answer as correct so others can get help as well :)